# Oracle_VM-error at startup

Tags: virtualbox

I am using **Oracle** **vm** with windows as host machine and linux on VM. I had everything working, but once i used 'power off' when it took time to start. Since i am not able to start the OS on VM. I am getting errors as below.

**Error relaunching VirtualBox VM process: 5
Command line: '60eaff78-4bdd-042d-2e72-669728efd737-suplib-3rdchild --comment RedHat_Linux_64bit_4GB --startvm 42e4c558-83d4-431c-a971-71ca9e1f4112 --no-startvm-errormsgbox "--sup-hardening-log=C:\Users\bhargav.vijay.desai\VirtualBox VMs\RedHat_Linux_64bit_4GB\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"' (rc=-104)
where: supR3HardenedWinReSpawn
what:  5
VERR_INVALID_NAME (-104) - Invalid (malformed) file/path name.**

I am able to see a file in snapshots folder which is large in size. (2016-08-16T05-57-16-295692800Z.sav). Have uploaded an image. I am on lookout for solutions.

Comment: Whoever is the great mind to down vote this question should receive a pat. 

There are a bunch of folks here who work on Virtual Machines and face such issues time and again. And there are no easy solutions as well. 

 Fortunately for me, on restart of machine, the issue got resolved. If anyone cannot understand the question, please ask, instead of all this.

Answer (score 1):

Restart of the system helped me resolve the issue. Also the snapshot files (.sav extensions) are of no use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this one on HP Elite Book for some time and I found solution [here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/721590/windows-hardening/).

The solution is to go to
HP Sure Sense -> Settings -> Advanced Settings
and turn off Enhanced Thread Protection.

It's not my solution, but I hope it's good to have here for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This ref https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=82277 fixed issue for me for VB version 5.2.x on Windows 10.
I had tried other approaches like installing earlier versions of VB but nothing else worked for me.

Comment: I 'mistakenly' accepted an Oracle VB update to version 5.2.16 and problem resurfaced. Switching to VMWare as this is annoying.

Comment: Just to note Oracle VB version 5.2.14 runs ok for me. No sign of the 'Oracle_VM-error at startup'. The latest version - 5.2.18 - did have the error though. I'll keep VMWare as backup!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a new HP Elitebook with Windows 10 preinstalled.

Install Virtualbox and import applience worked fine, and can be startet.
But after next restart of the System Virtualbox always shows an Error...

... supR3HardenedWinReSpawn what: 5 VERR_INVALID_NAME (-104) - Invalid (malformed) file/path name.

I tryed 4 Days to fix the Problem inclusive deactivate preinstalled hp client security, windows defender etc.

Nothing worked until I found the Link of the latest post.
I had to reinstall Virtualbox and deactivate the VBoxdrv sevice in the registry.

After every Windows start i need to start the service manualy or over shedule...
After that Virtualbox starts correctly!

I tested a lot. Windows seems to destroy the Virtualbox installation while driver was loading on startup. 
If the error occures once, one has to reinstall Virtualbox and deactivate the service... deactivate after the Error has already showen dosent work.

Answer (score 0):

a) Clear AppData/Local/Temp

b) Completely uninstall any VirtualBox currently installed

c) Restart the computer

d) Install the latest version of VirtualBox

e) After install completes do not restart the computer

f) Open the registry editor. Start > Run > regedit
Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VBoxDrv
Edit the key called Start. Change it's value from 1 to 3

g) Close the registry editor and restart your computer. After your computer restarts you should be able to use VirtualBox without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "turn windows features on or off" in the start menu and check that the "virtual machine platform" checkbox is active.